# UIImagepickerController cameraOverlayView in iOS 5

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5

I am writing an augmented reality app. I can present my UI as an overlay over the UIImagePickerController by adding subviews to its cameraOverlayView. This has worked well all along, but in iOS 5, I can't see any of the subviews of cameraOverlayView.

What gives?

Comment: would you be able to post just that section of code so the community can help with it?